# Any fast and robust implementation to calculate the minimum bounding box of a 3d point cloud?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, implementation, bounding-box

I have been looking online but have yet to see a fast and robust implementation, rather than crude implementations on forums.

Anyone knows of one?

Comment: What is a "crude implementation", and what is wrong with it?

Comment: I meant ones using improper methods that doesn't handle every case, like inverse transform object, compute its AABB and then transform both back, etc.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what you mean by "point cloud".  I'm assuming you just mean "a collection of points in 3D space"?  Or is it something more complex?  I would assume you simply have to loop over all points, and track min/max in each dimension.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Yeah I mean "a collection of points in 3D space", basically this: http://www.gamasutra.com/features/20000203/lander_figure_03.gif So it has to be minimum but also aligned, not AABB, but OBB.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - the box isn't necessarily aligned on x,y,z. Imagine a box tilted in all three directions.

Answer (score 1):

There's a description of a [3D OBB algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms) on Wikipedia.